# How to handle error with Gateway API and Lambda Proxy?

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

From Lambda in Node.js when something is wrong I am responding the following:

```
            if (error) {
                logger.error(error.errorMessage, error.stack);
                callback('Error getting some data', {
                    statusCode: 500,
                    headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
                });
            }
```

Testing the endpoint directly from Gateway API console I can see the following response:

[image]

Summarising:

1. I am responding from Lambda with a 500 error
2. In the API I can see a 502 error response

Could someone explain this strange behaviour?

Comment: Are you able to go to the CloudWatch log stream created for your Lambda to debug if the Lambda function is even being run. Are you sure you have a Proxy Integration to your Lambda function from API gateway setup? Does the API gateway have permission to invoke Lambda functions?

Comment: Yes, the lambda function is running and I can see the logs in Cloudwatch. And yes it is a proxy integration lambda. Everything works normality apart for the error response. When I return 200 from the same lambda all is good. Only the error responses seems odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the first parameter of the callback function. I was doing this:

```
if (error) {
   logger.error(error.errorMessage, error.stack);
   callback('Error getting some data', {
      statusCode: 500,
      headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
   });
}
```

when I needed to pass null as a first parameter to the callback. For instance:

```
if (error) {
   logger.error(error.errorMessage, error.stack);
   callback(null, {
       statusCode: 500,
       headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
   });
}
```

Another option is to return the object directly without calling the callback function.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
   return response = {
            statusCode: 500,
            headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                errorMessage: "This is a custom internal server error"
            })
        };
};
```

Why?. My guess is that the first parameter of the callback is only evaluated when you are customising the responses from Gateway API. In other words, when you don't have proxy integration with your lambdas.

But I am not 100% sure. Maybe someone could give a better explanation.